# Pandas - Add leading "0" to string values so all values are equal len

Tags: python, string, pandas

I have a column, `code_x`. I converted it to `.astype(str)`. Some example values are `45362.0, 75345.0, 346157.0, 572575.0`. I would like them all to be 6 digits. aka: `045362, 075345, 346157, 572575`

I am trying the following, but it does not work:
`f3[df3['code_x'].str.len() == 7] = "0" + df3[df3['code_x'].str.len() == 7]['code_x']`

Suggestions?

Comment: Do you want to right justify them adding 0 to left side?

Comment: @AnandSKumar I think so? I'll update the original question to give an example of what I would like. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even I am with @DSM for using zfill. But I think using lamba makes it much cleaner and easy to read.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([45362.0, 75345.0, 346157.0, 572575.0], columns=['code_x'])

In [3]: df.code_x.apply(lambda x: str(int(x)).zfill(6))
Out[3]: 
0    045362
1    075345
2    346157
3    572575
Name: code_x, dtype: object
```

Note: We are converting a given value to int before converting to string to get rid of ".0" in results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`Series.str.rjust`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.rjust.html) method to right justify the string values and use `8` as the length and `0` as fill value. Example -

```
df3['code_x'] = df3['code_x'].astype(str).str.rjust(8,'0')
```

Demo -

```
In [65]: df
Out[65]:
        A
0    blah
1  supbla
2       a

In [69]: df['A'].str.rjust(6,'0')
Out[69]:
0    00blah
1    supbla
2    00000a
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: oh that makes a lot of sense. do you know how I can do this and get rid of the .0, also? The .0 was not in the original number but is present after i converted it to string

Comment: if you are converting from numeric types, you can try casting to `int` before converting to `str` using `astype()`. Another method, would be to use `str.slice` .

Comment: I don't think I can use `int` because there are some `NaN`s in the original set.

Comment: `df3['code_x'].astype(int)` errors: `Cannot convert NA to integer`

Comment: For this also, there are two options. 1. You can use the keyword argument `raise_on_error` , set it to `False` for `astype()` method. 2. You can use `Series.fillna()` method to convert `NaN` to some default value (like `0` or so) before converting.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use [`str.zfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html#pandas.Series.str.zfill) which means you wouldn't have to special-case by length:

```
In [16]: ser
Out[16]: 
0     45362
1     75345
2    346157
3    572575
dtype: float64

In [17]: ser.astype(str).str.zfill(8)
Out[17]: 
0    045362.0
1    075345.0
2    346157.0
3    572575.0
dtype: object
```